# django CheckboxSelectMultiple - how to add scrollbar?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating add/edit view for my model. I have a many-to-many relationship and I would like to display it as checkboxes instead of default SelectMultiple.
I did some research and I've found that the only thing I need to do is to add something like

```
    objects = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), queryset=RelatedObjects.objects.all())
```

in my ModelForm.

It works. But now I have many RelatedObjects entries in database. 
The question is very simple: how can I add scrollbar as in default SelectMultiple widget?

If it is important, I'm using django-bootstrap3 to render my form in template.

Cheers,

Comment: I think it'd be easiest to handle with css on the template. Do you have an element wrapping that form field? You could use that selector and add a ```height``` style to it.

Comment: Maybe the better solution would be using many to many as it is in admin view ?
http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2010/05/14/reuse-djangos-filter_horizontal-admin-widget.html

Comment: @schillingt - the problem is, I'm using django-bootstrap3, that's why I'd like to avoid doing this in css/html.

Comment: If you really want to, I suppose you could set the style attribute on the widget. ```widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={"style":"height:100px;"})```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Passing the height attribute to the SelectMultiple will only change the height of each select option which is not what you want.
Here is how I did it.
In the admin.py file put:

```
Class Mycls:
    Media:
        js = ('js/hack.js',)
```

then in your statis/js/hack.js
write a javascript that resizes the div that is the parent of that list.
In order to find out id or class of the div, you'd need to use your browser's debugger.
Example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".filtered").attr('style', 'height:100px;overflow:scroll;');
});
```